# .NET Core 5.0 Runspace.Open() doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, powershell

I'm trying to start a Runspace instance to fire up some Powershell commands. But the program gets stuck if I use the "runspace.Open()" method. After some time the method fails with the error message:

```
System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException HResult=0x80131501 
Nachricht = The background process reported an error with the following message: D 
Quelle = System.Management.Automation
```

That are the coresponding lines of code:

```
Runspace rs;
var pspi = new PowerShellProcessInstance();
pspi.Process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
pspi.Process.Start();
rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(new TypeTable(new string[0]), pspi);
rs.Open();

using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create()) {
    powershell.Runspace = rs;
    powershell.AddScript(<some code>);
    var output = powershell.Invoke();
}
```

I'm using a .NET Core 5 console application and the the following packages:

- Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK
- System.Management.Automation

If I run the same code within a .NET Framework console application, everything works just fine. Any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the parameterized constructor of the PowerShellProcessInstance and therefore, start the Powershell in Server Mode:

```
Version psVersion = new Version("5.1");
TypeTable type = new TypeTable(new string[0]);

powershellInstance = new PowerShellProcessInstance(psVersion, null, null, false);
powershellInstance.Process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";

runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(type, powershellInstance);
runspace.Open();
```